# What is the proper way to use @property in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subclass

I have following code, Dog and Cat class is inherited from Animal class. and Person class is using Dog and Cat class as its instance. I would like to have function to return instance's name like string "get the name xxx" for john instance and john's property dog, cat's name. I have tried to wriiten the property *namegetter* under Animal class and Person and I can get what I want. however, if there is even a proper way to do that? so if I have couple of class like Person, I do not need to write the same property under the class

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def namegetter(self):
        return 'get the name of {}'.format(self.name)

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.space = 'park'


class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.dog = Dog("dog's food", "dog's name" )
        self.cat = Cat("dog's food", "cat's name")

    @property
    def namegetter(self):
        return 'get the name of {}'.format(self.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Person('john')
    print(john.name) #john
    print(john.dog.name) #dog's name
    print(john.cat.name) #cat's name
    print(john.dog.namegetter) #get the name of dog
    print(john.cat.namegetter) #get the name of cat
    print(john.namegetter) #get the name of john
```

Comment: Are you asking if there's another way you can get the instance's `name` out that doesn't use `@property`? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: not really, I want to know if there;s another way to get instance's name with "get the name of " from john, john.dog, john.cat without using @property or do not write the same property twice

Comment: They aren't the same property (even though the implementations look the same), because they act on unrelated objects. Perhaps you want a common base class like `NamedEntity` (that `Animal` and `Person` both inherit from) that defines the `name` property.

Comment: you can implement `__str__` for your `Animal` object to return name. Then you can use it like: `print john.dog`. But in general what's you have implemented is ok. Probably you can make a class like `Nameble` or whatever where you have constructor with name + getter. Your objects just should extend from it.

Comment: I gave you an example below for Either an additional base class or a Mixin (use the base class here, the Mixin helps with more complicated structures). Your code is quite okay, though.

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, I would be very happy, if you could mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I guess you want to avoid defining the same method twice.
You could do that with Mixins (in a complex hierarchy) or just another base class. As for your question on whether or not you can avoid writing `@property`: You can leave it out, but then you would have to write braces behind your method `namegetter()`.

Example using a base class:

```
class NamedEntity(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def namegetter(self):
        return 'get the name of {}'.format(self.name)


class Animal(NamedEntity):
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.space = 'park'


class Person(NamedEntity):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Person, self).__init__(name)
        self.dog = Dog("dog's food", "dog's name" )
        self.cat = Cat("dog's food", "cat's name")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Person('john')
    print(john.name) #john
    print(john.dog.name) #dog's name
    print(john.cat.name) #cat's name
    print(john.dog.namegetter) #get the name of dog
    print(john.cat.namegetter) #get the name of cat
    print(john.namegetter) #get the name of john
```

In a more complex example, you could use a Mixin instead, this would basically change the way you inherit from it in the class definition:

```
class NamedEntityMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def namegetter(self):
        return 'get the name of {}'.format(self.name)


class Animal(NamedEntityMixin, object):
    # Imagine object being another parent class with additional properties and methods
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.space = 'park'


class Person(NamedEntityMixin, object):
    # Imagine object being another parent class with additional properties and methods
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Person, self).__init__(name)
        self.dog = Dog("dog's food", "dog's name" )
        self.cat = Cat("dog's food", "cat's name")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Person('john')
    print(john.name) #john
    print(john.dog.name) #dog's name
    print(john.cat.name) #cat's name
    print(john.dog.namegetter) #get the name of dog
    print(john.cat.namegetter) #get the name of cat
    print(john.namegetter) #get the name of john
```

### Setters

In the comments you asked about what if someone wants to write to `namegetter`. Above, I only defined readonly access, since the name `namegetter` sounded to me as if you need that. Below, I defined you a version with getters and setters that allow you to set the format string with the optional variable `{name}` being replaced on demand:

```
class NamedEntity(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._namegetter = "get the name of {name}"

def _get_namegetter(self):
    return self._namegetter.format(name=self.name)

def _set_namegetter(self, namegetter):
    self._namegetter = namegetter

namegetter = property(_get_namegetter, _set_namegetter)


class Animal(NamedEntity):
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'
        self.namegetter = 'catnamegetter'


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.space = 'park'


class Person(NamedEntity):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Person, self).__init__(name)
        self.dog = Dog("dog's food", "dog's name" )
        self.cat = Cat("dog's food", "cat's name")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Person('john')
    print(john.name) #john
    print(john.dog.name) #dog's name
    print(john.cat.name) #cat's name
    print(john.dog.namegetter) #get the name of dog
    print(john.cat.namegetter) #get the name of cat
    print(john.namegetter) #get the name of john
```

I split up the getter & setter into two methods and made them available as the `namegetter` property. Python will select the right method based on how you access the property automatically.

The above solution however does not use decorators anymore, which might make the code less readable. A version with decorators is this one. Please note that the method `namegetter` is defined twice with different decorators:

```
class NamedEntity(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._namegetter = "get the name of {name}"

    @property
    def namegetter(self):
        return self._namegetter.format(name=self.name)

    @namegetter.setter
    def namegetter(self, namegetter):
        self._namegetter = namegetter



class Animal(NamedEntity):
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'
        self.namegetter = 'catnamegetter'


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.food = food
        self.space = 'park'


class Person(NamedEntity):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Person, self).__init__(name)
        self.dog = Dog("dog's food", "dog's name" )
        self.cat = Cat("dog's food", "cat's name")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Person('john')
    print(john.name) #john
    print(john.dog.name) #dog's name
    print(john.cat.name) #cat's name
    print(john.dog.namegetter) #get the name of dog
    print(john.cat.namegetter) #get the name of cat
    print(john.namegetter) #get the name of john
```

Comment: why i cannot put ```super().__init__(name)``` to use it?

Comment: and what if I have instance that is named exactly like * namegetter*. does that mean, some conflict occurs?

Comment: `super().__init__(name)` would work in Python 3, but you flagged your question for both Python 2.7 and Python 3, so I gave you the Python 2.7 example. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/1331407 for details.

Comment: I do not undrstand what exactly you mean by an instance named `namegetter`. As a value for the `name` property that is completely fine. You cannot save it as an additional attribute to `Person` though.

Comment: thank you i mean what if someone inherited Animal class like class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food, n):
        super().__init__(name=n)
        self.food = food
        self.sound = 'meow'
        self.namegetter = 'namegetter'

Comment: Right now, that would result in an AttributeError, since `@property namegetter` has been defined readonly. You could, however, add a setter in order to set whatever value you want in there. I will extend my answer accordingly.